# error calling pointer to member function in c++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, call

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool cmp(pair<int, int>& aa,pair<int, int>& bb){
        if(aa.first<bb.first) return true;
        else if(aa.second<bb.second) return true;
        else return false;
    }
    int maxEnvelopes(vector<pair<int, int> >& envelopes) {
        int i,sz;
        sz=envelopes.size();
        vector<int> v1,v2;
        vector<int>::iterator it1;
        vector<int>::iterator it2;
        sort(envelopes.begin(),envelopes.end(),cmp);
        for(i=0;i<sz;i++){
            it1=lower_bound(v1.begin(),v1.end(),envelopes[i].first);
            it2=lower_bound(v2.begin(),v2.end(),envelopes[i].second);
            if(it1==v1.end()&&it2==v2.end()){
                v1.push_back(envelopes[i].first);
                v2.push_back(envelopes[i].second);
            }
            else{
                v1[it1-v1.end()]=envelopes[i].first;
                v2[it2-v2.end()]=envelopes[i].second;
            }
            //cout<<v1.size()<<" "<<v2.size()<<endl;
        }
        return v1.size();
    }
};
```

---

I am getting `"error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function"`  And it redirects me to predefined_ops.h file when I compile code in codeblocks compiler.

Comment: First of all, *where* do you get the error? Please mark it out with a comment or something like that. Secondly, does the `cmp` function really need to be a member function? And why isn't it a `static` member function?

Comment: Thanks a lot :) . After using **static** member function it is working now.

Comment: [Whole page of useful information on pointers to member functions](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members). Also look at [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a non-`static` member function, such as `cmp`, as an argument to `sort`.

The argument to `sort` has to be a global function, a `static` member function, or a callable object.

Make `cmp` a `static` member function for your program to work.